How to migrate from Xamarin to Maui
The microsoft's maui has replaced xamarin which was better and much more stable to use. So am i the only one with this openion.
comparison of xamarin and maui.
I have been facing multiples issues with it, over time.
And these issues are making me frustrated , So could someone send me useful tips to navigate through maui.
